# What is the method for making an ADODB connection from VBA to a (Google) Cloud SQL database?

Tags: excel, vba, google-cloud-platform, adodb

Connecting to Cloud SQL appears to be different than connecting to normal MySQL databases.

I have added the 'Instance connection name' after the 'Public IP address'.

I am getting an error:

> 'Unknown MySQL server host'

```
Dim Cnn As Object
Set Cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Cnn.Open ("DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};SERVER=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\instanceConnectionName;DATABASE=databaseName" & ";USER=user;PASSWORD=abcd")

If Cnn.State = adStateOpen Then
    Debug.Print "Connection"
Else
    Debug.Print "No Connection"
End If
Cnn.Close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use the [SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app) and then for the connection would be like if the database was in your localhost.

So the steps would be:

- Install Cloud SQL Proxy in your computer
- Start the cloud SQL Proxy
- Connect as I f you were connecting to a local database

the code would be:

```
Dim Cnn As Object
Set Cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Cnn.Open ("DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};SERVER=172.0.0.1;DATABASE=<DATABASENAME>;USER=<USERNAME>;PASSWORD=<PASSWORD>)

If Cnn.State = adStateOpen Then
    Debug.Print "Connection"
Else
    Debug.Print "No Connection"
End If
Cnn.Close
```

Comment: Thank you! Where do I enter my proxy invocation strings?   https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/connect-admin-proxy#start-proxy   I set up a service account previously. I can't seem to load that option into Cloud SDK command line.

Comment: on the command line you prefer, it can be on CMD or in Powershell

Answer (score 0):

What kind of DB are you connection to?  You can find all kinds of connection strings here.

https://www.connectionstrings.com/

Also, go to your ODBC drivers and see what you have installed.  Your code has to match what you have installed.  Here is an image of what I have on my system.

[image]

So, for instance, you have to have 'MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver' installed because that's what you are referencing in your code.  Try that and feed back with your findings and results.

Comment: Thanks! That is a great resource! My 'MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver' is installed. I have used it many times to connect to other MySQL databases, but it's not working so awesome connecting to MySQL databases on Cloud SQL!